# Output two lines separately to the console in PHP

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have written this small PHP script which counts from 0 to 9 while also showing the sum of the counted numbers.

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$line = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $sum += $i;
    echo str_repeat(chr(8), strlen($line)); // cleaning the line
    $line = "Counter: {$i} | Total: {$sum}";
    echo $line; // Outputing the new line
    sleep(1);
}
echo "\n";
```

As you see, on each iteration, I am cleaning up the line (`8` is the ASCII code for `backspace`) and showing the new text in the same line.

This works fine, but now I want to show the Count and the Total in two different lines and animate the two lines in the same way that I did with one line. So I tried this code:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$line = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $sum += $i;
    echo str_repeat(chr(8), strlen($line)); // cleaning the line
    $line = "Counter: {$i}\nTotal: {$sum}";
    echo $line; // Outputing the new line
    sleep(1);
}
echo "\n";
```

The issue here is that `backspace` stops at the `\n` character and so it deletes the second line but leaves the first line as it is which gives the following output:

```
Counter: 0
Counter: 1
Counter: 2
Counter: 3
Counter: 4
Counter: 5
Counter: 6
Counter: 7
Counter: 8
Counter: 9
Total: 45
```

Is there a proper way to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: `echo 'something'.PHP_EOL;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please read the full question before answering :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a working soution:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$line = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $sum += $i;
    $line = "Counter: {$i}\nTotal: {$sum}";
    echo $line; // Outputing the new line
    sleep(1);
    echo chr(27) . "[0G"; // go to the first column
    echo chr(27) . "[1A"; // go to the first line
    echo chr(27) . "[2M"; // remove two lines
}
echo "Total: {$sum}\n";
```

This takes benefit from some ansicodes, check [This document](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/ansicode.txt) for more details.

Thanks @Joshua Klein for help.

Answer (score 1):

Really lame answer (works on linux):

```
    <?php
$sum = 0;
$line = '';
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $sum += $i;
    echo str_repeat(chr(8), strlen($line)); // cleaning the line
    $line = "Counter: {$i}\nTotal: {$sum}";
    echo $line; // Outputing the new line
    sleep(1);
    system("clear");
}
echo "\n";
```

The real answer has something to do with the \r (linefeed) or different ansicodes characters which you can read about here:
 [Clear PHP CLI output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320081/clear-php-cli-output)