# Character moving horizontaly from left to right in specified line length (CLI)

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Is there a way to get such moving result in one line without getting 7 lines?

For example made it like this:

```
$trackLength = 18;
$playerSymbol = "_";
$emptyTrack = array_fill(0, $trackLength, $playerSymbol);
$playerList = ["#", "X", 1, "$", "Y", 2, "!", "Z", 3, "@", "C", 4];
$ChosenPlayer = [];
$makePlayerTrack = [];

$randomMin = 1;
$randomMax = 2;
$oneStep = $randomMax - 1;

$runningInProgress = true;
$reachedFinish = [];


$playerCount = (int) readline("Please enter amount of participants: ");
if (!is_numeric($playerCount) || !(0 <= $playerCount && $playerCount < count($playerList))){
    echo "Invalid input, should be from ";
    exit;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $playerCount; $i++){
    $makePlayerTrack[$i] = $emptyTrack;
    $ChosenPlayer[] = $playerList[$i];
    $makePlayerTrack[$i][0] = $ChosenPlayer[$i];
}

while ($runningInProgress) {
    usleep(50000);
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $playerCount; $i++){
        echo implode(" ", $makePlayerTrack[$i]) . PHP_EOL;
        
        $position = array_search($ChosenPlayer[$i], $makePlayerTrack[$i]);
        $randomSpeed = rand($randomMin, $randomMax);
        
        if ($position < $trackLength - 1){
            $makePlayerTrack[$i][$position] = $playerSymbol;
            if ($position === $trackLength - 2){
                $makePlayerTrack[$i][$position + $oneStep] = $playerList[$i];
            } else{
                $makePlayerTrack[$i][$position + $randomSpeed] = $playerList[$i];
            }
            //echo $randomSpeed . PHP_EOL;
        } else{
            $reachedFinish[] = $ChosenPlayer[$i];
            $reachedFinish = array_unique($reachedFinish);
        }
        if (count(array_unique($reachedFinish)) === $playerCount){
            echo PHP_EOL;
            echo "Winner board: " . PHP_EOL;
            for ($i = 1; $i < $playerCount + 1; $i++){
                echo "{$i}. " . $reachedFinish[$i - 1] . PHP_EOL;
            }
            $runningInProgress = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**:

To sum up:

**Expected input could be string**: $character = "#"; or string in array $character = ["#"];
**This string is moving in predefined string field with certain length:** "_"
Movement happens with heartbeat like steps using function: `sleep(1);`
Movement step amount could be changed for example with: `rand(1,3)`, meaning after 1s passed and `echo` refreshes, the `"#"` could be from:
`#______` to `___#___`, by jumping 3 steps if that is the result of `rand(1,3)`;

**Expected output in echo with step 1**:

```
#______
_#_____
__#____
___#___
____#__
_____#_
______#
```

Is there a way to get such moving result in one line without getting 7 lines?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide examples of both input and expected output?

Comment: Post updated, with working code, but question still needs to be answered.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320081/clear-php-cli-output